# mongo nested aggregation with join

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've following tenant collection:

```
{id: 1, name: "T1", type: "DEFAULT", state: "ACTIVE"},
{id: 2, name: "T2", type: "DEFAULT", state: "DISABLED"},
{id: 3, name: "T3", type: "STANDARD", state: "ACTIVE"},
{id: 4, name: "T4", type: "TRIAL", state: "DELETED"},
{id: 5, name: "T5", type: "DEFAULT", state: "DISABLED"}
```

and then second collection with options:

```
{id:1, tenantId: 1, opt: "OPERATING"},
{id:2, tenantId: 2, opt: "OPERATING"},
{id:3, tenantId: 3, opt: "POSTPONED"},
{id:4, tenantId: 4, opt: "DELETED"},
{id:5, tenantId: 5, opt: "POSTPONED"}
```

Id' like to aggregate this collections to get umber of tenant types grouped with number of operations, but I'd like to remove all `DELETED` tenants and all `DELETED` options from search. Something like this:

```
{type: "DEFAULT", count: 3, opts: {operating: 2, postponed: 1}}
{type: "STANDARD", count: 1, opts: {postponed: 1}}
```

Grouping the tenants is fine, but I don't know what should I use for that next grouping of options.

```
db.tenant.aggregate([
  {$match: { state: {$ne: "DELETED"}}},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "option",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "tenantId",
    as: "options"
  }},
  {$group {
    _id: "$type",
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `type` and get group of ids
- `$lookup` with pipeline match `$in` condition for `tenantId`
- `$group` by opt and get count of option
- `$project` to show fields in k and v format
- `$project` to show required fields, `$size` to count total tenant and `$arrayToObject` convert opts array to object

```
db.tenant.aggregate([
  { $match: { state: { $ne: "DELETED" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      ids: { $push: "$id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "options",
      let: { ids: "$ids" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { opt: { $ne: "DELETED" }, $expr: { $in: ["$tenantId", "$$ids"] } } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$opt",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$count"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "opts"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      type: "$_id",
      count: { $size: "$ids" },
      opts: { $arrayToObject: "$opts" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oc-hzoVYDMo)